# How to Find all elements in an array that are greater than all elements

Tags: python

- I have a list `[10, 5, 20]`

Expected out is {5:2, 10:1, 20:0}

- there are 2 greater number than 5 so value for 5 is 2
- there are 1 greater number than 10 so value for 10 is 1
- there are 0 greater number than 20 so value for 20 is 0

Logical Code is below

```
myd = {}
#iterate through the list
for each in list_:
  #check the element not exist in dict
  if each not in myd:
    # check the greater than condition
    if each < other numbers:
      # if already exists
       myd[each] += 1
    else:
       myd[each] = 1
```

Comment: I would suggest sorting the list and returning their indexes. From your example I take order of the entries is not important?

Comment: What will you do with duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the sorted version of the list, iterate it and set the corresponding dictionary element to the reversed index (counting from the end) of the iterated value:

```
# Example input (including a duplicate)
lst = [1, 5, 5, 10]

last = len(lst) - 1
d = {}
for i, val in enumerate(sorted(lst)):
    d[val] = last - i

print(d)  # {1: 3, 5: 1, 10: 0}
```

Comment: last - i why we need to do that

Comment: Just to save time in the loop, otherwise that inner expression would be `d[val] = len(lst) - 1 - i`. We want to count the number of values *after* the current value, so we subtract the current index from the index of the last element, which is `last`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use comprehension, and pass Boolean generator expression to `sum` function

```py
>>> {v:sum(v<i for i in l) for v in l}
{10: 1, 5: 2, 20: 0}
```

You need to sort the resulting dictionary based on count later:

```py
>>> dict(sorted(result.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1]))
{5: 2, 10: 1, 20: 0}
```

You can also sort the  list then iterate it using `enumerate` and then assign the number of elements remaining to be read.

```py
l.sort()
result = {}
n = len(l)-1
for idx,v in enumerate(l):
    result[v] = n-idx
    
result
{5: 2, 10: 1, 20: 0}
```

**PS:** The second approach might fail if there are repeated numbers in the list (I have not tested it for duplicates).

Comment: This should be a somewhat slow solution if the dataset size is quite big.

Comment: Not getting for huge range of documents

Answer (score 1):

1st solution: by counting

```
list = np.array([5,10,20])
result = {}
for elmt in list:
   s = np.sum(list>elmt)
   result[elmt]=s
```

2nde solution: by sorting the list (only if there is no duplicate)

```
list = [5,10,20]
list_sorted = list.sort(reverse=True)
result={elmt:i for i, elmt in enumerate(list_sorted)}
```

Comment: Looks like you where a little quicker than me

Comment: Does this give the right result when the input have duplicate values?

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer as well haha

Comment: The first will give the right result the second won't

Answer (score 1):

```
    # any list
    num = [10,5,20]
    num.sort()
    result = dict(zip(num,range(len(num)-1,-1,-1)))
    print(result)
```

This `code` can solve your problem. If only your list does not contain any duplicates. you can use the below code to solve your question if there are any duplicates or not.

```
    # any list
    num = [10, 5, 5, 1, 20]
    # removing duplicates
    arr = list(set(num))
    arr.sort()
    # count greater values for each number in list "arr"
    count = list(map(lambda x:len(list(filter(lambda y:x<y,num))),arr))
    result = dict(zip(arr,count))
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following algorithm:

```
1. Sort the list.
2. For index from 1 to N:
    greatest_index_of_current_element = findGreatestIndex[index]
    print(list[index], N - greatest_index_of_current_element)
    index = greatest_index_of_current_element + 1
```

**Time Complexity:** O (N * log(N))

Answer (score 0):

And yet another one using a sorted list and enumeration - with the twist of using only the unique numbers to get to the correct outputs as

```
[1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5] # still has only 1 value smaller then 5
```

so if we use the set of the list we got correct values.

```
from random import choices, seed

#     numbers = [1,5,5,10]
#     numbers = list(set(numbers))
seed(42)

stop_at = 100
k = choices(range(stop_at ), k = stop_at) # random perm numbers
k = sorted(set(k)) # only uniques

k.sort() # O(n*log(n))

lk = len(k)
d = {key:lk-idx-1 for idx,key in enumerate(k)}

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: 64, 2: 63, 3: 62, 4: 61, 6: 60, 7: 59, 8: 58, 9: 57, 10: 56, 
 15: 55, 16: 54, 17: 53, 19: 52, 20: 51, 21: 50, 22: 49, 23: 48, 
 24: 47, 26: 46, 27: 45, 28: 44, 31: 43, 33: 42, 34: 41, 36: 40, 
 37: 39, 38: 38, 39: 37, 42: 36, 45: 35, 50: 34, 52: 33, 53: 32, 
 54: 31, 55: 30, 56: 29, 57: 28, 58: 27, 60: 26, 61: 25, 62: 24, 
 63: 23, 64: 22, 65: 21, 67: 20, 68: 19, 69: 18, 70: 17, 72: 16, 
 73: 15, 77: 14, 79: 13, 80: 12, 82: 11, 84: 10, 86: 9, 87: 8, 
 89: 7, 91: 6, 93: 5, 94: 4, 95: 3, 97: 2, 98: 1, 99: 0}
```